# validate Property through object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I validate the property through object? I have define the list of  Property in the `checkProperty`

I expected `missingFields` to return `Batch.Name` is missing.

Currently is is outputting `[ 'Batch.Id', 'Batch.Name' ]` which is wrong.

```js
let data = {
    Batch: {
        Id: 123,
    },
    Total: 100,
}

let checkProperty = ['Total', 'Batch.Id', 'Batch.Name'];

let missingFields = [];
checkProperty.forEach(field => {
    if (!data[field]) {
        missingFields.push(field);
    }
});

console.log(missingFields);
```

Comment: I maintain a minimal JavaScript type checking library. It can do something along the lines of what you are expecting. Might be worth taking a look. [typy](https://github.com/flexdinesh/typy#isvalid-schema-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use something like `reduce` after splitting on dots to check whether the nested value exists:

```js
let data = {
  Batch: {
    Id: 123,
  },
  Total: 100,
}

let checkProperty = ['Total', 'Batch.Id', 'Batch.Name'];

let missingFields = [];
checkProperty.forEach(field => {
  const val = field.split('.').reduce((a, prop) => !a ? null : a[prop], data);
  if (!val) {
    missingFields.push(field);
  }
});

console.log(missingFields);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this**

`The reason why this`data[field]`when do`data[Batch.Id]`it tries to check at the first level key of object. in our case we don't have any key such as`Batch.Id`.`

```
For our case we need `data[Batch][Id]` something like this which first searches 
 for `Batch` property and than or the found value it searches for `Id`.
```

```js
let data = {
    Batch: {
        Id: 123,
    },
    Total: 100,
}

let checkProperty = ['Total', 'Batch.Id', 'Batch.Name'];

let missingFields = [];
checkProperty.forEach(field => {
    let temp = field.split('.').reduce((o,e)=> {
     return o[e] || data[e]
    },{});

    if (!temp) {
        missingFields.push(field);
    }
});

console.log(missingFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use additional libraries Ajv is perfect for this. Instead of creating all the logic by yourself, you can create a schema and validate it.

```
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Batch": { 
        "type": "object", 
        "required": ["Id", "Name"],
        "properties": 
        {
        "Id":{},
        "Name":{},
        },
       },
    "Total": {}
  }
};


let json = {
  Batch: {
    Id: 123,
  },
  Total: 100,
}

var ajv = new Ajv({
    removeAdditional: 'all',
    allErrors: true
});

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
var result = validate(json);
console.log('Result: ', result);
console.log('Errors: ', validate.errors);
```

Returns the following error message:

```
dataPath:".Batch"
keyword:"required"
message:"should have required property 'Name'"
params:{missingProperty: "Name"}
schemaPath:"#/properties/Batch/required"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95m7z4tw/